# Can I use IFormatProvider with a WPF Binding to a custom type?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, string-formatting, iformatprovider

I have a custom type (`SINumber`, which represents an SI number with appropriate units and prefix). I can bind to a `SINumber` fine and override `SINumber.ToString()`, but what is displayed is the result of calling SINumber.ToString().

For example, SIMeasurement is of type `SINumber` with an SI value of 3099999.9046325684 Ω. Using the following Binding, I get an output of 3.09999990463257 MΩ.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SINMeasurement}"></TextBlock>
```

The units (Ω) and prefix (M = mega) conversation are correct, the problem is with the number of numerals displayed. I want to be able to use a custom formatter (implementing `IFormatProvider`  `ICustomFormatter`?) to interpret the `StringFormat` from the Binding, and incorporate my SI-logic (changing prefix) to display **3.10 MΩ**. Below is an example of the Binding I would like to use, where the precision is customizable (0.00 in this case), and the location of the units are determined by the 'U'.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SINMeasurement, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00 U}'}"></TextBlock>
```

Any thoughts? I don't want to use the hard-coded `SINumber.ToString()`, as the desired precision will vary in different locations within the application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make your data type implements **IFormattable** interface. Its method **public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)** will be called each time the Binding converts your object to string using **StringFormat** that you specify for the Binding.